# How do I replace string with string if exist

Tags: python

Hello Guy's I have question
How do I replace string in string if string exist.
Example:

```
list=['20':'1','40':'2','60':'3','80':'4','100':'5']

#I have this line:
x='abcd abcd 60'
num='60'
if num in x:
print('The new number is: ')
```

and it will print 3 instead of 60, how can I do that and otherwise if in x will be 80 it will replace it to 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

Just a couple notes first, you seem to have confused the syntax for dictionaries.  Dictionaries start with `{` and end with `}`. `[` and `]` are used for `list`s and they don't have `:` (a list looks like: `[1,2,3,4,5]`.  The following code will iterate through all the keys in the dictionary and then replace them properly in the string.

```
li={'20':'1','40':'2','60':'3','80':'4','100':'5'}

string='abcd abcd 60'
for key in li:
    string = string.replace(key,li[key])

print(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

a dictionary would probably be easier, so it would go something like this:

```
list={'20':'1','40':'2','60':'3','80':'4','100':'5'}
x='abcd abcd 60'
num = '60'
if num in x:
    print('The new number is: '+list[num])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dictionary={str(20*i):str(i) for i in range (5)}
text='abcd abcd 60 40'

for key in dictionary.keys():
    text=text.replace(key, dictionary[key])
print (text)
```

Will print `abcd abcd 3 2`

Edit: Answer to updated question

```
for key in dictionary:
    if key in text:
        print (dictionary[key])
```

Care as this will only work if you don't have keys which are a substring of an other key (i.e. *term* & ***term**inal*), in that case you can always recur to regular expressions.